# Download file from vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

I need a script that can be run on freshly installed windows xp+ and download specified files from internet, like http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6.2/python-2.6.2.msi
Is it any easy way to do it without hand-crafting HTTP/FTP requests or using third-party programs like wget? I can suggest that WScript.CreateObject("internetexplorer.application") will do the magic, but documentation on it is extremely huge and Google is silent, as always :).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just found this [one](http://blog.netnerds.net/2007/01/vbscript-download-and-save-a-binary-file/) pasted below. You can run it with cscript and have it scheduled.

```
   'Set your settings

    strFileURL = "http://www.domain.com/file.zip"
    strHDLocation = "D:\file.zip"

   ' Fetch the file

    Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    objXMLHTTP.open "GET", strFileURL, false
    objXMLHTTP.send()

    If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
      Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
      objADOStream.Open
      objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary

      objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
      objADOStream.Position = 0    'Set the stream position to the start

      Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If objFSO.Fileexists(strHDLocation) Then objFSO.DeleteFile strHDLocation
      Set objFSO = Nothing

      objADOStream.SaveToFile strHDLocation
      objADOStream.Close
      Set objADOStream = Nothing
    End if

    Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
```

Comment: +1 for streamline code. This looks much more efficient than using WScript.CreateObject("internetexplorer.application").

Answer (score 2):

VBScript is annoying unco-operative when it comes to doing things like this. This sort of thing always requires COM servers that aren't formally part of the scripting engine.

Maxwell's suggestion of using MSXML2.XMLHTTP seems a cool way round this. I must admit I hadn't come across that trick before. There are also various commercial COM servers that will do file downoads.

This type of problem is one of the reasons I'm looking at shifting much of my VBScript to Powershell. Because Powershell can seamless use .Net objects, doing such things is a lot easier.

JR

Comment: I second migrating to PowerShell if at all possible. While it isn't a direct answer to the original question - in most cases it would be the right path forward.

Answer (score 1):

The method using

```
Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
```

is more elegant, unfortunately is not very portable since the version of the object changes a lot throughout the versions and updates of Windows.

Using

```
WScript.CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
```

is probably better but less elegant.

Answer (score 1):

MSXML2.XMLHTTP is built around the old WinInet. There's a newer interface called Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP, which is more reliable. It is built on a newer MS WinHTTP stack. I suggest calling WinHTTP directly.

Just use CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1") instead of creating an MSXML2.XMLHTTP object. The rest of the code stays the same.