# How can I download a file from the command line on a default Windows installation (i.e. without installing wget)?

Tags: command-line-interface, http, windows

I have access to the command line on a Windows host. I want to trigger a download to this host purely from the command line. The catch is that I am not able to copy anything to this host prior to my use of the command line.

Using an installed instance of Internet Explorer is OK, as is using a Windows Scripting Host script or anything else that comes preinstalled on your average Windows host (let's say Windows 2003).

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have posted a vbscript doing a file download in this [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/29707/download-file-from-vbscript/29720#29720). Hope this fits your needs.

Answer (score 3):

If your host allows FTP, all versions of windows come with a command line ftp clients, just run 'ftp' from a command line.

Answer (score 1):

the TFTP client is installed by default on windows server 2003.   Great for getting trojans onto compromised windows servers in one command!  Which is why it's been removed in newer OSes.

```
tftp server1 get file.txt
```

The FTP client can achieve the same purpose with a little more work using a [script file](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/96269).

Comment: Including a TFTP client is a security risk, huh? I'd say the same would apply to all other TCP/IP clients included with any OS...

Comment: used to be *the* way to deliver a payload via IIS exploits.  One of the security _hardening_ strategies was to remove it